# Non parametric test/ANOVA/Parametric test?

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, spss, nonparametric

My study design is a pre-post test measurements with a control group. My study design is Creatine Kinase being measured before and after exercise, and my subjects are divided into two groups; either a Vitamin C group or Control (No Vit C) group.

For example, a data set would look like this

```
Participant      Creatine Kinase (Pre exercise)    Creatine Kinase (Post exercise)  Group 
1                       84                               240                         VitC
2                      212                               190                      Control
```

My data set is non normally distributed, so I'm pretty confused on what type of statistical test is most appropriate to run in this instance?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Sorry, the data got messed up above..


It should look a little like this:


Participant   CK(Pre)    CK(Post)  Group
1              120         180      Vit C
2             210          190      Control


Edit: The data is not being shown properly for some reason.. I hope you can understand my study design

Comment: Data sets with discrete measures such as "treatment group" usually hesitate to look normal. This is no tragedy though. To understand your question a bit better: How would you analyze your research question (=?) if you would not need to care about normality assumptions at all?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Are you asking what statistical test I would run if I wouldn't need to care about normality assumptions? Well, past authord have utilised a 2 way mixed model anova, having first log transformed their data to ensure normality assumptions are met

Comment: What are the skewness and kurtosis values for your outcome (Creatine Kinase) at pre/post exercise?

Comment: The skewness and kurtosis values for pre (CK) are : .790 (skewness) and -.166 (kurtosis), and for post (CK) : 2.816 (skewness) and 9.057 (kurtosis)